# Probability of having money after throwing $n$ times the coin

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

We consider the following game of chance:

An unfair coin with probability $p =0.49$ for tail is thrown $n \in  \mathbb{N}$ times.

With every throw you lose one euro, when we get head and wins one euro when we get tail.

So for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_n$ independent random variables such that $P [X_j = 1] = 0.49$ and $P [X_j =-1] = 0.51$ for all $j \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$.

The account balance after $n$ throws then corresponds to $S_n = X_1 + X_2 +\ldots + X_n$.

Show that the probability that after throwing $n$ times the coin we have money in the account has converged to $0$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$.

$$$$

So do we have to calculate the expected value for the sum?

For one toss we have $E[X_i]= 0.49-0.51 =-0.02$, right?

Is then $E[S_n]=n\cdot E[X_i]=n\cdot (-0.02)$ ?

$$$$

**EDIT :**

Using the weak law of large numbers we have :
\begin{align*}P\left (|\overline{X}-\mu|\geq \epsilon\right )\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon^2} &\Rightarrow P\left (|\frac{1}{n}S_n-\mu|\geq \epsilon\right )\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon^2}\\ & \Rightarrow P\left (|S_n-n\mu|\geq n\epsilon\right )\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon^2}\\ & \Rightarrow P\left (S_n\geq n\epsilon+n\mu\right )\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon^2}\\ & \Rightarrow P\left (S_n\geq n\epsilon-0.02n\right )\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon^2}\end{align*} We choose $\epsilon$ such that $n\epsilon-0.02n=0$, so $\epsilon=0.02$ and so we get $$P\left (S_n\geq 0\right )\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{n0.02^2} \rightarrow 0$$ Is that correct?

Or do we use the Bernoulli version of weak law of large numbers? Then we would have :
\begin{align*}P\left (|\overline{X}-p|\geq \epsilon\right )\leq \frac{1}{4n\epsilon^2} &\Rightarrow P\left (\left |\frac{1}{n}S_n-p\right |\geq \epsilon\right )\leq \frac{1}{4n\epsilon^2}\\ & \Rightarrow P\left (\left |S_n-np\right |\geq n\epsilon\right )\leq \frac{1}{4n\epsilon^2}\\ & \Rightarrow P\left (S_n\geq n\epsilon+np\right )\leq \frac{1}{4n\epsilon^2}\\ & \Rightarrow P\left (S_n\geq n\epsilon+0.49n\right )\leq \frac{1}{4n\epsilon^2}\end{align*}

Or do we have to do that in a completely different way?

Comment: maybe your account had a starting positive sum on it and it cannot go negative?

Comment: I got stuck right now. You mean that we have to add the initial amount that we had? @Exodd

Comment: You don't want to calculate $E[X_i]$ (which you do correctly). Are you able to continue to bet with a negative balance? If so, the question is just to compute $P(S_n > 0)$. If not, the problem is an example of [Gambler's ruin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin#Unfair_coin_flipping).

Comment: It doesn't give us any restriction if we can continue or not, does it? Do we maybe have to use the weak law of large numbers? @preferred_anon

Comment: Could you take  a look at the edit part of my question? @preferred_anon

Comment: @MaryStar I think your first solution is OK in the case of finite variance of the $X_i$ (which is trivial to prove). There is a more direct solution which I'll post.

Comment: Is the variance equal to $\text{Var}(X_i)=E[X_i^2]-(E[X_i])^2=\left (1^2\cdot 0.49+(-1)^2\cdot 0.51\right )-\left (-0.02\right )^2=0.9996$ ? @preferred_anon

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, alternatively computed as $p(1-p) = 0.51*0.49$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not hard to show that your sum $S_n$ is (a small variation of) a binomial random variable. That is, you can work out explicitly that

$$P(\tfrac{S_n + n}{2} = k) = \binom{n}{k} 0.49^{k}0.51^{n-k}$$

So

\begin{align*}
P(S_n>0) &= \sum_{k>n/2}^{n} \binom{n}{k} 0.49^k 0.51^{n-k}\\
&= 0.51^n \sum_{k>n/2}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{49}{51}\right)^k\\
&< 0.51^n \left(\frac{49}{51}\right)^{n/2}  \sum_{k>n/2}^{n} \binom{n}{k}\\
&< 0.51^n \left(\frac{49}{51}\right)^{n/2} 2^n\\
&= \left(0.51 \sqrt\frac{49}{51} \cdot 2 \right)^n\\
\end{align*}

and the base of the power can be shown to be very slightly less than 1.